# brackets elements meaning after a struct type A{a, b, c}

Tags: c++, c++17

What does passing objects inside brackets after a struct type means when it doesn't refer to the struct attributes or the arguments of its own constructor.

```
template <class... Ts> // (1)
struct Print : Ts... {
    using Ts::operator()...;
};

template <class... Ts> // (1)
auto MakePrint(Ts... ts) {
    return Print<Ts...>{ts...};
}
```

The `ts...` in the last line, running this code without it produce exactly the same result but I don't understand why it compiles :s

The only two interpretations that I know of the use of brackets, is to set the attributes of a struct or to call the constructor of the struct

But in this case for example with:

```
auto m = MakePrint ([](int i){ return i + 1;});
```

It is equivalent to:

```
auto MakePrint (typeof(lambda) lambda) {
   return Print<typeof(lambda)>{lambda};
}
```

and Print is defined in the following manner:

```
struct Print : typeof(lambda) {
    auto operator() (int i) { return i + 1; }
}
```

and so where does the object lambda inside the brackets (return `Print<typeof(lambda)>{lambda};`) go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in C++17 aggregates can have base classes.  So since `Print` inherits from `Ts..` doing

```
Print<Ts...>{ts...}
```

creates a `Print` object and initializes all of the base classes with an instance of each base class.  Looking at an expanded simple example your code is basically the same as

```
struct foo
{
    int f;
};

struct bar : foo {};

int main()
{
    foo f{42};
    bar b{f};
}
```

where `b`'s `foo` part is initialized by `f`.

Comment: So why do we need the template deduction guide ? here:
`template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;

std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; },
        }, v);`

as we don't call the constructor overloaded(Ts...), it doesn't supposed to exist :s

Comment: @Alex You need a deduction guide because `overloaded` does't have a constructor which it can use to deduce the type from.  Since you don't specify the type in the call to `visit` the only way to get it is with a deduction guide.

Comment: So how deduction guide works ? What I understood is that, if you use the constructor that has the same signature as the deduction guide then the compilator use the corresponding type, but here we aren't using a constructor as we use the brackets style

Comment: @Alex Class template argument deduction is a 2 phase process.  First it takes all of the constructors and deduction guides and synthesizes functions out of them.  It then goes through overload resolution to find the best match. If that passes then it uses the types it figures out as the types for the template parameters.  After that it runs through overload resolution and find a constructor that matches the arguments. This means CTAD can use a guide to determine the type, and then use aggregate initialization to actually initialize the object.

Comment: This is how `std::array` works since it doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: @Alex Here is a really great talk that really helps to understand CTAD: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-H-ut6j1BYU&feature=share